# Google Test and a proper design of mock classes for reducing redundancy

Tags: googletest, googlemock

Consider a base class B and two inheriting classes D1 and D2. B has a public function called "start", which calls a pure virtual function "run" under a condition returned by function "someCondition". The function run is implemented by classes D1 and D2, each classes is using is own logic, represented by functions "d1Condition" and "d2Condition".

Example code:

```
class B {
public: 
    virtual ~B() {}
    void start() { if (someCondition()) run(); } 
    virtual bool someCondition() { return true; } 
protected:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class D1 : public B {
public:
    D1();
    virtual ~D1() {}
    virtual bool d1Condition() { return true; }
protected:
    virtual void run() {
        if (d1Condition()) {
            //some code
        }
    }
};

class D2 : public B {
public:
    D2();
    virtual ~D2() {}
    virtual bool d2Condition() { return true; }
protected:
    virtual void run() {
        if (d2Condition()) {
            //some code
        }       
    }
};
```

I would like to write a unit test for "run" scenario for classes D1 and D2. I can write a mock class for D1 and another one for D2. The mock class for D1 will have a mock function for d1Condition and the mock class for D2 will have a mock function for function d2Condition. However, in ordedr to start the scenario, I need another mock function for someCondition(). This mock method will act the same for both tests of D1 and D2 - it should return true, in order for the function run to be called.

 How do I avoid redundancy of mock method for someCondition ?

Answer (score 0):

To me, you've implemented [strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy). Both D1 and D2 are solving the same problem using different approaches. Just create pure virtual protected method called `runCondition` in the base class:

```
class B {
public: 
    virtual ~B() = default;
    void start() { if (someCondition()) run(); } 
    virtual bool someCondition() { return true; } 
protected:
    void run() {
        if(runCondition()) {
            // some code
        }
    }
    // each derived class needs to implement this step in a different way
    virtual bool runCondition() = 0;
};
```

From here, you have 3 things to test: class B directly to check that `runCondition` and `run` are called when `start` is called (e.g. using partial mocking - you can create `PartialBMock` where `someCondition` and `runCondition` will be mocked and test what happens when `start` is called). Then you'll need to test `D1` and `D2` for their `runCondition`: i.e. to see under what conditions `run` will be called. If these `runCondition`s implementations are hard to test - extract them to separate classes and use mocks in `D1` and `D2` tests.